# Retrieve numeric values which are not with alphanumeric with dot using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

Hi can some one help me to extract only digits from string which are separate .. Assume my string is as follows

```
AB12(100).HJI(20).D76R(222)
```

I need output to be like:

```
  100.20.222(I need to get the digits which are in brackets appended with dot)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It' rather simple:

```
var value = @"AB12(100).HJI(20).D76R(222)"; 
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(value, @"(?<=\()(\d+)(?=\))");  
var result = String.Join(matches, ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another improvisation:

```
string input = "AB12(100).HJI(20).D76R(222)";
string output = string.Join(".", Regex.Matches(input, @"\((?<value>\d{1,})\)").OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["value"].Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = @"AB12(100).HJI(20).D76R(222)"; 
var matches = Regex.Matches(value, @"(?<=\()(\d+)(?=\))");
var result = String.Join(".", matches.OfType<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [this](http://regexr.com?31ts0) replace regex:

```
/[A-Za-z0-9]+\((\d+)\)/$1/g
```

The `C#` code would be:

```
string input = "AB12(100).HJI(20).D76R(222)";
string pattern = @"[A-Za-z0-9]+\((\d+)\)";
string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another version

```
 string text = "AB12(100).HJI(20).D76R(222)";
 MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(text, @"\(\d+\)"); //(100)(20)(222)
 string[] digits = new string[match.Count];

 for(int i=0; i<digits.Length;i++)
 {
     digits[i] = match[i].Value.Trim(new char[]{'(',')'});
 }
 string output = String.Join(".", digits); //100.20.222
```